# Set that is an open ball in the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ induced by d defined by: $d(x,y) = \{0$ when $x = y; 1+|x-y|$ when $ x \neq y\}$

Tags: general-topology

Open balls for a metric are defined for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon > 0$ as $B_d(x,ε) = \{y \in \mathbb{R}\ s.t.\  d(x,y) < \epsilon \} $.

Sets that are an open ball in the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ on induced by d, defined by $d(x,y) = \{0$ when $x = y; 1+|x-y|$ when $ x \neq y\}$: $(4,5)$, $(2,3) \cup (3,4)$, and $(-2,2)$.

Alternative $[4,6]$ is not because it isn't an open set.

I'm not sure about $\{3\}$ but I don't think it's a set that is an open ball in the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ on induced by d... (it has no radius?)

Feedback on these examples? Thanks.

Comment: It might just be me, but I think for readability's sake it would be useful if the metric you've defined were also in the body of the question and not just the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider for any $x \in \mathbb R$ and $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ the open ball $B_d(x,\epsilon)$. You should now see, that every singleton (one-element set) is open. Now you know that arbitrary unions of open sets are open and you will see, that everything is open. This is btw called the discrete topology.

PS: Maybe you have some problems with the notations, hence to see something:
\begin{align*}
(4,6)&= \{y \in \mathbb{R}\ s.t.\  |5-y| < 1 \}\\
&= \{y \in \mathbb{R}\ s.t.\  |5-y|+1 < 2 \}\\
&= \{y \in \mathbb{R}\ s.t.\  d(5,y) < 2 \}=B_d(5,2)
\end{align*}
So this is even an open ball. Moreover we have $[4,6]=\{4\}\cup (4,6) \cup \{6\}$ as union of open sets, hence it is open.

Comment: So $(-2,2)=B_d(0,2)$, $\{2\}=B_d(3,2)$, and $(4,5)=B_d(\frac{9}{2},2)$?

Comment: @ctst Wait... $|5-4|<1$?

Comment: Should it not be less or equal?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist, Olba Oh, yes, fixed the typo...

Comment: @Learner Close, $(-2,2)=B_d(0,3)$. $\{2\}=B_d(2,\delta)$ for any $\delta<1$ and $(4,5)=B_d(\frac{9}{2}, 2)$